# How to insert link before specific character

Tags: php, string

This is video chunk file i get this from file_get_contents and store it in my variable now i want to do some changes in this string i want to put my url before all

> n_

starting of every n_ line like this

> http://example.com/n_1_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=9142491

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:8
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:5.005,
#EXTINF:5.005,

n_1_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=9142491
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_2_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=9142491
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_3_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=9142491
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_4_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=9142491
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_5_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=9142491
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_6_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=9142491
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_7_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=9142491
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_8_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=9142491
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_9_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=9142491
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_10_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=9142491
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_11_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=9142491
```

Comment: Show us your current code and where you are stuck.

Comment: i have get this string from url now i am stuck here and don't know how to put my url before all n_ u can see that in my question i have no code

Comment: Take a look at `preg_replace()`, then you can check if the string starts with an 'n' and replace it with what you want.

Comment: yes i know it will done by preg_replace but i don't know about regex could u please answer by code then i can try and give u right vote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simple task - use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
<?php
$txt = '#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:8
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:5.005,
#EXTINF:5.005,

n_1_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=9142491
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_2_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=9142491
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_3_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=9142491
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_4_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=9142491
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_5_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=9142491
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_6_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=9142491
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_7_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=9142491
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_8_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=9142491
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_9_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=9142491
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_10_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=9142491
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_11_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=9142491';

// ^ means from beginning of string
// m modifier is using for multi line string - its combine with ^ modifier
// 
$txt = preg_replace("/^(n_)+/m",'http://example.com/$1',$txt);
#$txt = preg_replace("/^n_/m",'http://example.com/n_',$txt);
echo $txt;
```

Comment: its working but it replace n_ with my urls i don't want to replace i want to put my url before n_

Comment: you are changing n_ into: http://example.com/n_
so you are putting url before n_ isn't ?

Comment: i really appreciate this answer its working good please do something with it so it could not replace n_